# How to dynamically update a tool tip when using materialize

Tags: material-design, materialize

I am using materializecss in my app script add-on, When I try and add a tooltip dynamically the tip does not update with the new label. I have tried several variations and even double-checked that the tip was being changed, which it was.  The problem is that it does not seem to reinitialize with the updated text.

Here is a jfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/edlisten/grafo4su/1/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.5/css/materialize.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.5/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

     <script>
         $(function() {
          $('.tooltipped').tooltip({delay: 50,tooltip:"new",position:"bottom"});
        });
        </script>
      </head>
      <body>

      <div class="container">
      <a class="btn tooltipped">Hover me!</a>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What you can do is set an id to the anchor.
Lets say `<a class="btn tooltipped" id="tooltip">Hover me!</a>`

Now we can find easily the element with jquery.

```
var anchorElement = $('#tooltip');
```

Materialize has an atribute `data-tooltip` you need to have on the element so that the tooltip will pop out.

```
anchorElement.attr('data-tooltip', 'New tooltip value');
```

And finally we need to initialize the materialize tooltip on the element

```
anchorElement.tooltip();
```

You can play around with it and put it in a function.

Comment: I tried so many variations, and I thought I did exactly what you did to start off with.   Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: thank you for the solution, Vasil. Note: For some reason,  anchorElement.data('tooltip', 'New tooltip value'); does not work the same way.